# LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg. : Table parameter "m{'width'}"

Tags: tables

! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{'1cm'} | m{'1cm'}| m{'1cm'} | } 
\hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ 
\hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I got the error for it. Any hint for me please ? Thank you

Comment: Why do you have quotes around your lengths?

Comment: Without quotes around the lengths, it also gives the same error @Au101

Comment: Have you loaded the `array` package (`\usepackage{array}`)? In any case, quotes around the lengths is definitely wrong

Comment: Just a little additional advice for next time. Always include a full [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which should be compilable as-is and include a preamble. As we saw here, one of the problems seems to have been in the preamble. Second, it's a little unsporting to change the question as we go along, it makes good answers redundant, moves the goalposts, and can be confusing to future users. By all means edit the question as needed, but don't correct errors as the community solves them

Answer (score 11):

Remove the `'` (single-quote) characters from the arguments of the `m` column type:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | m{1cm} | m{1cm}| m{1cm} | }
```

*Addendum*: It is assumed that you're loading the `array` package or a package (such as `tabularx`) that loads the `array` package. The `array` package defines the `m` column type.

Comment: Without quotes around the lengths, it also gives the same error @Mico

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul What packages are you using? The `m` column is unknown in base configuration.

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul - Since you're using the `m` column type, I was assuming that you are loading the `array` package or, alternatively, a package such as `tabularx` that loads the `array` package. Is this assumption unwarranted?